# First parts of Array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

My object 'kim' has two elements I am trying to push values to, tips and fullBill. When the values are calculated within a method and then pushed to tips and fullBill, the console shows that the arrays in empty with the exception of only one value at the end.

I did the very same calculation to 'john', and for some reason, the arrays are showing up correctly with this one. Any idea why?

I've tried changing element names and switching them around so they are the same with no success.

```js
var kim = {
  fullName: 'Kim Lachance',

  hotelBills: [50, 304, 287, 199, 289],

  calcTips: function() {
    this.tips = [];
    this.fullBill = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.hotelBills.length; i++) {

      var bills = this.hotelBills[i];
      var percentage;

      if (bills < 200) {
        percentage = .15;
      } else if (bills >= 200 && bills <= 300) {
        percentage = .10;
      } else {
        percentage = .05;
      }
    }

    this.tips[i] = bills * percentage;
    this.fullBill[i] = bills + bills * percentage;

  }
}


var john = {

  fullName: 'John Smith',

  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],

  calcTips: function() {
    this.finalBills = [];
    this.tips = [];

    //Determine tips based on tipping rules

    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      var percentage;
      var bill = this.bills[i];

      if (bill <= 50) {
        percentage = .2;
      } else if (bill > 50 && bill < 200) {
        percentage = .15;
      } else {
        percentage = .1;
      }
      //Add tipping values to corresponding arrays
      this.tips[i] = bill * percentage;
      this.finalBills[i] = bill + bill * percentage;
    }
  }
}

john.calcTips();
kim.calcTips();
console.log(kim, john);
```

[image]

Comment: You're setting `this.tips[i]` after your for loop, not inside your for loop

Comment: You use these variables out of scope: bill, percentage while assigning this.tips[i] and this.finalBills[i]

Comment: In Kim move the `}` from  `} this.tips[i] = bills * percentage; this.fullBill[i] = bills + bills * percentage;` to `this.tips[i] = bills * percentage;this.fullBill[i] = bills + bills * percentage; }`

Answer (score 1):

you excellently move the calculation outside of the for in kim place and this is why this happend to you

```
     calcTips: function() {
        this.tips = [];
        this.fullBill = [];
    
        for (var i = 0; i < this.hotelBills.length; i++) {
    
          var bills = this.hotelBills[i];
          var percentage;
    
          if (bills < 200) {
            percentage = .15;
          } else if (bills >= 200 && bills <= 300) {
            percentage = .10;
          } else {
            percentage = .05;
          }

        this.tips[i] = bills * percentage;
        this.fullBill[i] = bills + bills * percentage;        
        }
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful, I'm new to javascript, I couldn't catch this before.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out in the comments, your problem is right here:

```
calcTips: function() {
    this.tips = [];
    this.fullBill = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.hotelBills.length; i++) {

      var bills = this.hotelBills[i];
      var percentage;

      if (bills < 200) {
        percentage = .15;
      } else if (bills >= 200 && bills <= 300) {
        percentage = .10;
      } else {
        percentage = .05;
      }
    } // <-- outside for loop

    // at this point, i = 5, so you are assigning it to the 6th spot with the first 5 being empty
    this.tips[i] = bills * percentage;
    this.fullBill[i] = bills + bills * percentage;
  }
```

Simply move the `this.tips[i]` and `this.fullBill[i]` lines into your `for` and you should be all set.